# R list toJSON without slash symbols

Tags: json, r, list

I have a list:

```
 [[1]]$period
 [1] "DAY"

 [[1]]$dates
 [1] 1.361743e+12 1.362348e+12 1.362953e+12 1.363558e+12 1.364162e+12 1.364764e+12                1.365368e+12 1.365973e+12 1.366578e+12
```

I want to put this list to json:

```
toJSON(my_list)
```

answer:

```
[
    {
        \"period\": \"DAY\",
        \"dates\": [
            1361743200000,
            1362348000000,
            1362952800000,
            1363557600000,
            1364162400000,
            1364763600000,
            1365368400000,
            1365973200000,
            1366578000000
        ]
    }
]
```

The answer is with slash symbols "\".

How to get rid of slash symbols? Maybe I  should apply another function, to parse my_list to json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash is just R's escape character. Used in this context it allows a quotation mark without closing the string. Although it appears in R console output, it doesn't appear when writing out to a file and it and the character you are escaping are counted as a single character:

```
x <- "ab\"c"
x
[1] "ab\"c"
writeLines(x)
ab"c
nchar(x)
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! writeLines(x) is a function, I was looking for.